# how to pass a parameter to my regex and loop on an array to find the word corresponding to my parameter

Tags: javascript, css, splunk, spl

I want to add span class to highlight each word on a table corresponding to my parameter value.

Now, I can add a span class only when I tape the word on a regex parameter like this : patt=/40/igm;
I use this solution just to test but i want to use my parameter "token"
(only declared but not yet used)

```
render: function($td, cell) {
    let token = tokens.get('search_tok'); //search word
    patt=/40/igm; //test with regex parameter
    let value=cell.value; //cells values
    while (matcher = patt.exec(cell.value)) {
        console.log(matcher.index + ' ' + patt.lastIndex);
        value = value.slice(0, matcher.index) + '<span id="highlight_search">'+cell.value.slice(matcher.index, patt.lastIndex)+'</span>'+cell.value.slice(patt.lastIndex);
        }}
```

Currently :
- this only add the span class to the word 40 but I want to add it to the word searched (token)
- also when i try with the number 4 only (so with only one character) this not work very well...

Comment: Before diving into javascript, did you try the inline color formatting?

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.6/Viz/TableFormatsFormatting#Format_table_columns

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to highlight only the word on the cell and not the cell completely :)
I did it in js